# Maybe need a HTML5 mockup tool now

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Flash is dead on Chrome, cannot create a mockup on site now.

Comment: Agreed. Although the feature itself was used less and less frequently as time went on, and image sharing online is far more mature than it was back when that was conceived, so perhaps we don't need any alternative?